# How can I pass a Text widget to a function in another module

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to pass a Text widget to another file? I have a `main.py` file and a second file named `fuction.py`. Can I do the following?

in the `main.py`:

```py
myText = Text(miFrame,width = 117, height = 18).place(x=20, y = 171)

function.some_function(myText)
```

And in the `function.py`:

```
def some_function(myText):
     myText.insert(END, "bla bla bla")
```

When I try to execute the above code I receive the following message:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 1):

I think `.place()` method of the `Text` does not return anything. What you probably want in `main.py` is:

```
myText = Text(miFrame, width=117, height=18)
myText.place(x=20, y=171)

function.some_function(myText)
```